# What is OverlappedData and how to clean a memory from this? C#

Tags: c#, sockets, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Using `System.Net.Sockets` I run `ReceiveAsync()` method and it works correctly. But when a client program shuts down, the socket leaves `OverlappedData` in memory. What is it and how can I remove it? Unfortunately I can't just leave it, because is it a memory leak. Could you help me, please?
`15 000 000` is a size of the socket's buffer to receive messages.
[image: OverlappedData]

I tried to find some solutions to solve the problem but I didn't succeed.

Comment: Show some code m8.
Here what I found on google https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/83500

Comment: You didn't say whether you are using Socket, TcpClient, etc.  But no matter which it is, you should dispose it when done, to free such resources.

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but windows calls its asynchronous api for "Overlapped IO". So it might be some internal buffer used by the socket to handle asynchronous data. Such memory *should* be released once you dispose the socket and release any remaining references to it. So, have you disposed the socket?

Comment: Yeah, I have. Just in case I first use Disconnect, Shutdown, Close and Dispose to close Socket and SocketEventArgs. I do it to be sure that all recources will be released. And they will. But as I said, they leave OverlappedData. I use Socket, not TcpClient.
And I equal buffer to null to release resources. I hope it works like that, yeah?

Comment: Max Naumov - Well. They decided to use Receive instead of ReceiveAsync and that helped. If I don't find any solutions, I will do the same. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. One of the solutions is using `Receive()` instead of `ReceiveAsync()`. It does work correctly and it doesn't create any memory leaks.
But I'd still like to know if there is any way to remove `OverlappedData` from memory. I can't believe that there is no way to use `ReceiveAsync()` without creating memory leaks.

[image: Receive()]